# delete duplicates records leaving unique in group with priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table that is generated by procedure that I cannot modify and that is returning data like so:

```
USER_ID     ACTIVE_STREET      STREET
----------- -----------        -----------------
1           1                  STREET1
1           0                  STREET1
1           0                  OTHER STREET
2           0                  OTHER USER STREET
2           0                  OTHER USER STREET
2           0                  OTHER USER STREET
2           1                  OTHER USER STREET
```

I need to remove records from this table following this rules:

- Every user has **only one** active street.
- I must delete duplicates but only removing those that have `ACTIVE_STREET` set to 0

So I'd like to leave only these records:

```
USER_ID     ACTIVE_STREET      STREET
----------- -----------        -----------------
1           1                  STREET1
1           0                  OTHER STREET
2           1                  OTHER USER STREET
```

I've tried grouping but there is no id column so I can't get id's to delete.
How can I delete those duplicates without altering original table structure?

**EDIT - based on Gordon's answer**
this is really close, but there is a litle difference:

```
IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#MY_TMP' ) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #MY_TMP;
    END;
SELECT * INTO #MY_TMP
  FROM(
      SELECT 1 AS USER_ID,
             1 AS ACTIVE_STREET,
             'STREET1' AS STREET
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS USER_ID,
             1 AS active,
             'OTHER USER STREET' AS STREET
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS USER_ID,
             0 AS active,
             'STREET1' AS STREET
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS USER_ID,
             0 AS active,
             'OTHER STREET' AS STREET
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS USER_ID,
             0 AS active,
             'OTHER USER STREET' AS STREET
     UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS USER_ID,
             0 AS active,
             'OTHER USER STREET 2' AS STREET ) X;


SELECT *
  FROM #MY_TMP ORDER BY USER_ID, ACTIVE_STREET desc;

SELECT * FROM (
select USER_ID, MAX(ACTIVE_STREET) AS a, STREET
from #MY_TMP
group by USER_ID, STREET ) X ORDER BY USER_ID, a desc


;with todelete as (
      select row_number() over (partition by user_id, ACTIVE_STREET
                                     order by street) as seqnum
      from #MY_TMP t
     )
delete todelete
    where seqnum > 1;

    SELECT *
  FROM #MY_TMP ORDER BY USER_ID, ACTIVE_STREET desc;
```

Comment: So there are no completely equal rows?

Comment: @jarlh there might be some, I'll add one to question right away. Sorry for not pointing that at start.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
select user_id, active_street, min(street) as street
from atable t
group by user_id, active_street;
```

It returns the results that you specify.

If you actually want to delete rows from the table, you can use `row_number()`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id, active_street
                                     order by street) as seqnum
      from atable t
     )
delete todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3dec/1) is a SQL Fiddle that demonstrates the code.

EDIT:

Ooops, I think I misunderstood the logic.  You want to delete all streets that are the same as the active street with the flag = 0.  If so, this is the query:

```
delete t from my_tmp t
    where active_street = 0 and
          exists (select 1
                  from my_tmp t2
                  where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                        t2.street = t.street and
                        t2.active_street = 1
                 );
```

And [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2861e/1) is the SQL Fiddle for this one.

Comment: should't there be a max(street)? I'm testing this on larger data set

Comment: Could You please look at my edited question? I've tried Your solution, there is propably tiny thing to change and it will be perfect!

Comment: @Misiu `partition by user_id, street order by ACTIVE_STREET desc` will work, I think

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table. Move data to temp table, using `GROUP BY`:

```
insert into temptable
select USER_ID, MAX(ACTIVE_STREET), STREET
from tablename
group by USER_ID, STREET
```

When done, delete from original table and copy from temptable to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this variants will be applicable for your task?

```
-- Create table with sample data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MY_TMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MY_TMP
;
SELECT * INTO #MY_TMP
FROM (
VALUES ( 1, 1, 'STREET1'           )
,      ( 1, 0, 'STREET1'           )
,      ( 1, 0, 'OTHER STREET'      )
,      ( 2, 0, 'OTHER USER STREET' )
,      ( 2, 0, 'OTHER USER STREET' )
,      ( 2, 0, 'OTHER USER STREET' )
,      ( 2, 1, 'OTHER USER STREET' )
) T([USER_ID], [ACTIVE_STREET], [STREET]);
```

Variant using temp table:

1 - fill table with required ruesults;

2 - truncate source table;

3 - insert data from temp to source table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ToBeInserted') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ToBeInserted
SELECT [USER_ID]
,      [ACTIVE_STREET]
,      [STREET]
    INTO #ToBeInserted
FROM (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [USER_ID], [STREET]
                                        ORDER BY [STREET],[ACTIVE_STREET] DESC)
      FROM #MY_TMP) AS T
      WHERE RN = 1

TRUNCATE TABLE #MY_TMP

INSERT INTO #MY_TMP ( [USER_ID], [ACTIVE_STREET], [STREET] )
SELECT [USER_ID]
,      [ACTIVE_STREET]
,      [STREET]
FROM #ToBeInserted
```

Variant using CTE

```
WITH CTE
AS
(SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [USER_ID],[STREET] 
                                   ORDER BY [STREET],[ACTIVE_STREET] DESC) 
FROM #MY_TMP)

DELETE CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```